# Update selected check box data and remove unchecked data

Tags: php, mysql

Assume I have **users** database and `base_u_group` default will be 0 which are not under any groups.

```
1)base_users
|base_u_id|base_u_username|base_u_group|
------------------------------------------
|    1    |   username 1  |      0     |
|    2    |   username 2  |  2, 3, 4   |
|    3    |   username 3  |     4      |
|    4    |   username 4  |    3,5     |
```

List down all the users. `$checkBox` will be automatically checked when belong to that edit group.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo   "<td>". $count .". ".$row_User['base_u_username']. "</td>";
echo   "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class = \"group\" name=\"userList[]\" value=".$row_User['base_u_id']." ".$checkBox."/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

My problem is how do I insert selected check boxes data without duplication for example: 
`3, 3, 4, 5 --> 3, 4, 5` 
and when the check boxes are unchecked, it will delete that group in my `base_u_group` , for example unchecked the check box for **username 2** of **group 3**

```
2, 3, 4 --> 2, 4
```

`$gid` indicates the selected edit group.
This is what I did so far:

```
<?php
$userGroup = $_POST['userList'];

foreach($userGroup as $a)
{   
    $selSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM base_users WHERE base_u_id='".$a."'");
    while($row_SQL = base_fetch_array($selSQL))
    if($row_SQL['base_u_group'] != "0")
    {           
        $data = explode(", ",$row_SQL['base_u_group']);
        for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++)
        {
            //insert to user group if base_u_group does not find the group ID
            if($gid <> $data[$i])
                base_executeSQL("UPDATE base_users SET base_u_group='".$gid. ", ". $row_SQL['base_u_group']."' WHERE base_u_id='".$a."'");
        }
    }   
    //if the user does not belong to any groups: base_u_group = 0
    else
        base_executeSQL("UPDATE base_users SET base_u_group='".$gid."' WHERE base_u_id='".$a."'");
}
?>
```

EDIT: deletion of groups

```
$data = explode(", ",$row_SQL['base_u_group']);
$ok = true;
for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++)
{
    //insert to user group if base_u_group does not find the group ID
    if($gid == $data[$i])
    {
        $arr = array_merge(array_diff($data,array($gid)));
        $newArray = implode(", ",$arr);     
        base_executeSQL("UPDATE base_users SET base_u_group='".$newArray."' WHERE base_u_id!='".$row_SQL['base_u_id']."' AND base_u_domain='local'");
        $ok = false;
    }   
}
if (ok) base_executeSQL("UPDATE base_users SET base_u_group='".$gid. ", ". $row_SQL['base_u_group']."' WHERE base_u_id='".$a."'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current database design, then your approach is actually the easiest you can do. Moving this logic to MySQL would be very hard, and would have no advantages over your solution. Seems like your approach already handles all the requirements you posted for the adding a group to the user, and deleting the group is pretty much the same logic.

However, I would highly suggest changing your database design. Remove `base_u_group` column completely, and create a new table `user_groups` with two columns `user_id` and `group_id`. Make a unique key consisting of both of them. Now to add a group, just `INSERT` into that table, and the unique key will prevent you from inserting the same group twice. Deleting from a group is now also as trivial as deleting from that table. To get all the groups for the user, just execute `SELECT group_id FROM user_groups WHERE user_id=$user_id` (well, with proper escaping, or via a prepared statement).

You might also make `user_id` be a foreign key to your current table, so that it disallows inserting invalid `user_id`s. Also, if you have a table for groups, adding a foreign key from `user_groups` to that table would help avoid invalid group ids as well.

EDIT: Apparently I misunderstood part of your question. I thought you already have a working solution, and were asking for a better one. I can immediately see an issue in your solution, that causes duplicates, it is easy to fix, just make the following changes to your code:

```php
    $data = explode(", ",$row_SQL['base_u_group']);
    $ok = true;
    for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        //insert to user group if base_u_group does not find the group ID
        if($gid == $data[$i]) $ok = false;
    }
    if (ok) base_executeSQL("UPDATE base_users SET base_u_group='".$gid. ", ". $row_SQL['base_u_group']."' WHERE base_u_id='".$a."'");
```

To see why your code is wrong, think what happens if `$data = {1, 2}` and `$gid` is `2` (in which case you obviously don't want to add it). You iterate over every element of `$data`, so on the first iteration your `$data[i]` is `1`. Since `1 != 2`, you update your table and add another `2` at the end

With my changes, I first iterate over all elements of `data`, and make sure none of them is equal to `$gid`, and only if that's the case I run a query once to append `$gid` at the end.

Unfortunately, from your code it is not clear what kind of request you issue for delete, but the logic will be similar. You would go over every element of `data`, and if any of them is equal to what you want to delete, then just just remove it from `data` and break from the loop. Then `implode` your `data` and store it into the database with an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Thank you. I got your point and this method is really useful and solve my problem. But  is there any other solutions instead of change my database configuration due to uncertainty and unpredictable risk.

Comment: Why don't you like your current solution?

Comment: I have problems using my current solution that stated above. I can't figure out any solution on my problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get your logic :) Btw the delete part is when 
`name=\"userList[]\" value=".$row_User['base_u_id']." ".$checkBox."`is not checked, it will remove the current group from **base_u_group**

Comment: No, I would just remove the element from the `$data`, and then `implode` the `$data` to obtain the new string. (if you are not familiar with implode, it's the opposite of explode, it concatenates the array back into a comma-separated string)

Comment: You may check my edit, I have problem during insert of groups. For example I have following groups for 3 users respectively `3, 5` , `4` , `5`..But when I insert `$gid=3` for all users, it will update records to `3, 5` , `3, 5` , `3, 5`

Comment: `WHERE base_u_id!='".$row_SQL['base_u_id']."` -- I guess `base_u_id !=` should be `base_u_id =` (equality instead of inequality)?

Comment: The reason why I have to change **inequality** because I want to remove the check boxes data which are not checked. If I change to **equal sign(=)** , the check boxes data without checked will not be updated. `name=\"userList[]\" value=".$row_User['base_u_id']." ".$checkBox."` will get the value when the check box is checked

Comment: It should certainly be equality there, because you want to change the groups for a specific user. Replace it with the equality, and run your delete, and then query your database, you will see that it updates the groups properly. Anyway, good questions are small and self contained. The answer to your original question is "fix the issue with for insert as stated, and use implode for delete". Fixing particular bugs with the implementation should be separate questions.